# router.push not redirect to defined path and it's load current page instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, bootstrap-5

i'm new in NextJS and i'm getting stuck in the situation that i need to pass data from current page to another page, but instead of load defined path in router.push which is `pathname: "/booking/checkout/"`, but it's load current page.

i need to pass the data inside `GatherAllData()` function to another page to process that data in the destination page. when i clicked the `Proceed` button that has `onClick{()=>passData()` to load a function that has router.push to http://localhost:3000/booking/checkout?data, it's redirect to it's own page (http://localhost:3000/booking/details/3?data)

here is my code:

`details/[id]/index.tsx`

```
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Hotel from '../../../../src/api/booking/booking';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Layout from '@/src/components/layout';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import ProgressBar from 'react-bootstrap/ProgressBar';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import ButtonGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import DropdownButton from 'react-bootstrap/DropdownButton';
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function HotelDetails(){

    const router = useRouter();

    const {id} = router.query;

    ...

    const GatherAllData = () => {
        return (
            {
                "fullname": formvalues['fullname'],
                "email": formvalues['email'],
                "phone": formvalues['phone'],
                "accountnumber": formvalues['accountnumber'],
                "check_in": values.check_in,
                "check_out": values.check_out,
                "voucher_applied": values3,
                "total_discount": currencyFormatter.format(totalDiscount),
                "payment_method": selectedpayment,
                "add_on_id": addOnAdded()[1],
                "add_on_name": addOnAdded()[0],
                "grand_total": priceList(id)
            }
        )
    }

    const passData = () => {
        router.push({
            pathname: "/booking/checkout/",
            query: GatherAllData()
        })
    }

    return(
        <Layout>   
                
                ...

                  <Button variant='success' type='submit' onClick{()=>passData()}>Proceed</Button>
                                        
                ...
)}
```

`checkout/index.tsx`

```
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Hotel from '../../../src/api/booking/booking';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import ListGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ListGroup';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Layout from '@/src/components/layout';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import ProgressBar from 'react-bootstrap/ProgressBar';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import ButtonGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';
import DropdownButton from 'react-bootstrap/DropdownButton';

export default function HotelCheckout(){
   
    const router = useRouter();

    console.log(router.query)

    return(
        <Layout>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </Layout>
    )

}
```

index.tsx under pages folder

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import styles from '@/styles/Home.module.css'
import Layout from '@/src/components/layout'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import HotelList from './booking'
import HotelDetails from './booking/details/[id]'
import HotelCheckout from './booking/checkout'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>
        <HotelList/>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  )
}
```

my project pages folder structure

[image]

i want to when i click `Proceed` button it's redirect to booking/checkout page and passing the data from booking/[id]/details/index.tsx to booking/checkout/index.tsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "success" button is `type="submit"`.... so I suspect there is a `form` element involved somewhere here that is reloading the page, e.g. the `import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';`.

```
<Button
  variant='success'
  type='submit' // <-- submit button
  onClick{passData}
>
  Proceed
</Button>
```

There are a few options:

- On the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler you should call `preventDefault` on the `onSubmit` event object to prevent the default form action from taking place which results in the page reloading on the current URL path.

  If there's a submit handler this is also where you'd want to place the navigation logic.

  ```
  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- don't submit the form!

    ... the rest of the submit logic ...

    router.push({
      pathname: "/booking/checkout/",
      query: GatherAllData()
    });
  };
  ```

  ```
  <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    ...

    <Button
      variant='success'
      type='submit'
    >
      Proceed
    </Button>

    ...
  </Form>
  ```
- If there's not any `form` element involved, or maybe there's one rendered higher up in the ReactTree and you ***don't*** actually want to submit a form with this button then specify the button to ***not*** be a submit button

  ```
  <Button
    variant='success'
    type='button' // <-- regular old button
    onClick{passData}
  >
    Proceed
  </Button>
  ```

Comment: Oh wow, i forgot to delete type="submit" from that button. My god, i've been puzzled for 2 hours because of this. i copied that button from the one form in the same page and didn't check that again.